# Algebra, Local variables and the Module function

Tags: scoping, algebra

Algebra is so much fun but I'm struggling to understand how MMA executes local variables within `Module`. Reading the `Module` [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html?q=Module) I suspect it has something to do with "Before evaluating *expr*, Module substitutes new symbols for each of the local variables that appear anywhere in *expr* except as local variables in scoping constructs". But as I work through possible examples of how this works, the output behaviour continues to unpredictable. For example, what is causing the difference in output below? How would you explain this to a kindergartener? Or one's great grandmother?

In1=   `x=2;y=x+2;y+x`

`6`

in2=   `Module[{a=2,b=a+2},a+b]`

`4+a`

Comment: I'd have written the second one as `Module[{a = 2, b}, b = a + 2; a + b]`; the way you wrote it will not have `b` inherit the value of `a`.

Comment: sigh... hadn't tried that combo yet (or considered it). It's just like learning a new language.

Comment: Personally, I'd remove "just like" from the last sentence of your comment, and it'd be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the syntax coloring:

[image]

Note that the `a` in `b = a + 2` (blue) is colored differently than the `a` in `a = 2`. (green). That is because they are different variables.  The `a` in `b = a + 2` references the variable `` Global`a `` (usually displayed as just `a`). You can also [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace) the evaluation to see this:

```
Trace[Module[{a=2,b=a+2},a+b]]
```

> {Module[{a=2,b=a+2},a+b],{a\$40801=2,2},{a+2,2+a},{b\$40801=2+a,2+a},{{a\$40801,2},{b\$40801,2+a},2+(2+a),2+2+a,4+a},4+a}

Comment: Interestingly, my MMA Online notebook is not showing that: It's green across the board. This is difficult. Thanks so much for your time.